# Copy first column in blank lines

Tags: linux

I have the following type of file:

```
A
    a    b
    c    d
B
    e    f
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
A    a    b
A    c    d
B    e    f
```

And of course I have 10000 lines so doing it by hand is not an option. I was trying to imagine a solution with sed or cat and could not figure it out. Does anyone else has an idea?

Comment: Are those tabs or spaces in front of the lower case letters?

Comment: they are tabs! But can be changed if needed

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\t/) { print "$h\t$_" } else { chomp($h = $_) }' input.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-n` processes the input line by line
- `/\t/` checks for the presence of a tab
- if there's no tab, the line without the final newline (`chomp`) is remembered in `$h`.
- if there's a tab, the `$h` (last remembered "header") is printed, followed by a tab and the line itself.

Comment: thanks but it does not seem to be working, I don't know anything about Perl to try to debug it, just nothing happens! (sorry python user here!)

Comment: @user3188922: Is there's no output, there are no tabs in the input.